# File.toURL() deprecated?

Tags: java, url, io

Why is the function `java.io.File.toURL()` deprecated? I need to pass an URL to `Toolkit.createImage()` which accepts a URL object. Javadoc recommends me to use `File.toURI().toURL()`. However:

`C:\Documents and settings\Administrator\...`

becomes:

`C:\Documents%20and%20settings\Administrator\...`

which obviously is an invalid file location. I've found File.toURL() to create URL's without the escaping, however it's deprecated. Although it works I'm scared of using deprecated functions. What's a method that's not deprecated that does the same thing?

EDIT: Right now my code looks like:

```
spriteImage1 = tkit.createImage(new File("./images/sprite1.png").getCanonicalFile().toURL());
```

EDIT: I need to create an Image from a folder outside my .jar file. I'll need a relative location ("./images/sprite1.png"). The method createImage(String) throws an exception when I try to give it the relative path.

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me why you think the escaped version is wrong. Admittedly I'd probably expect + instead of %20, but I'd hope that it would still work.

Comment: Shouldn't the second be file:///C:/Documents%20and%20settings/Administrator/... ?

Comment: Actually the second version gives me an exception when passed to createImage() while the first works fine. And yes it's file:///...

Comment: Out of interest, what is the exception?

Comment: It's a NullPointerException when I try to draw an image loaded by createImage() that doesn't exist.

Comment: If it has un-encoded (%20) spaces in it, then it isn't a URL.  Stop lying to the computer.

Comment: Regarding your second edit: Did you try with file.getAbsolutePath() or just file.getPath()?

Answer (score 39):

Use:

```java
URL url2 = file.toURI().toURL();
```

Answer (score 14):

It does not handle special characters correctly as per [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6179468).

Answer (score 11):

Wouldn't it be easier to use [`Toolkit.createImage(File.getPath());`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage(java.lang.String)) instead?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just use the `createImage` function that [takes a String](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage(java.lang.String)) filename instead?

Answer (score 5):

I think the right answer to this question is the one exposed in this link http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1280051

As exposed in the link above, the right way to do this is:

```
// Supposing f is the referenced file in code and we want to
// get an URL instance without deprecation warnings.
URL externalForm = f.toURI().toURL();
```

There is no catch for MalformedURLException as the question is about deprecation of the method file.toURL().

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you must write the url in this way

> C:/Documents and settings/Administrator/...

not in this

> C:\Documents and settings\Administrator...